# My cron job gives an error message

Tags: web, cron, webserver

I set up cron command as follows:

```
php /home/mydomain.com/cron-test.php
```

But i received an error message via email:

```
status: 404 not found 
Content-type: text/html 
No input file specified
```

I have tried various commands and looked up my forums, but still unable to figure out. 
Pls tell me what the problem is. 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I moved the cron folder to outside public_html and it worked. Thanks!